# How to Start read a TextFile from Specific line using java

Tags: java, regex, string, file

I want to start read a TextFile from specific line
I have a text file like this

```
        #11
        mango
        apple
        orange
        END
        #22
        dog
        cat
        monkey
        END
        #33
        car
        bus
        van
        END
```

here i want to get all lines inbetween #22 and END

```
      String text = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("mypath")), 
      StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
      //multiple lines to single line
      text=text.replaceAll("[\r\n]+", " "); 
      Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("#22(.*?)END");
      Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);
      while (matcher.find()) {
          System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
      }
```

it gives output in one line(dog cat money).How to get only the below lines from File(line by line)

```
                dog
                cat
                monkey
```

I am not sure what number comes after a specific number(#22).#33 is for example.Any ways to get  only with #22 and END(before #33)

Comment: are You using java 8 or below?

Comment: i am using java 8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To match the last END you need to use `$` anchor like `"#22(.*?)END$"` which mean end of file, or you can remove `?` your regex should look like `"#22(.*)END"`

Also you mentioned :

> How to get only the below lines from File(line by line)

You can use `Pattern.DOTALL` like this :

```
//text = text.replaceAll("[\r\n]+", " ");// no need to this 
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("#22(.*)END", Pattern.DOTALL);
```

this will return :

```
    dog
    cat
    monkey
    END
    #33
    car
    bus
    van
```

---

**Edit**

> I want text between #22 and end(before #33)

In this can use this regex `#22((.*)#33(.*?))END`

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("#22((.*)#33(.*?))END", Pattern.DOTALL);
```

**Edit**

> Is there any way without giving #33 directly.because there numbers
>   will not be in order

You can use in this case, where the number can be given by the user :

```
int number = 33;
String regex = String.format("#22((.*)#%d(.*?))END", number);
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.DOTALL);
```

Comment: Thanks for your response.But this takes EVERYTHING after the #22.This is just an example i gave here. i have 5000 lines in my textfile

Comment: @priya wait! what lines you want to take, you mentioned between `#22` and last `END` did you have other data after last `END`?

Comment: Actually its not last end..end before #33

Comment: i want text between #22 and end(before #33)

Comment: @priya in this case Try this regex instead `"#22((.*)#33(.*?))END"`

Comment: Thanks.but i can use this regex only when i now #33.is there any way without giving #33 directly.because there numbers will not be in order

Comment: @priya in this case you can use my 3rd solution

Comment: Sorry if i am confusing you.As there is more than 5000lines in a textfile.I am not sure what number comes after a specific number(#22).thats why i asked  suggestions only with #22 and END(before #33)

Comment: @priya so if I can understand your question, you want to read any thing after `#22` and to the END after the next `#N` where N is a number no?

Comment: Yes you are right..but END BEFORE the next #N where N is a number

Comment: @priya in this case you can use `Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("#22((.*)#\\d+(.*?))END", Pattern.DOTALL);`

Comment: I used this regex it takes everything after #22...then i used the  index of to remove everything after FIRST  "END" ..Now i got the output..Thanks for your help.;)

Comment: Sure.Accepted:)

Comment: This is really bad to down-vote an accepted answer without any reason or any comment!!

Comment: I was just writing the reason - give me a chance ;-) This answer gives the correct results, but uses the same technique as the OP's question. A much more efficient way to do this would be to simply read each line using a BufferedReader and process the required lines and exit once the string "END" is encountered.

Comment: @KlitosKyriacou you can post an answer and mention this technique, instead of down-vote an accepted answer

Comment: Just wanted to make a short comment really. Not fussed about votes so withdrew it.

Comment: @KlitosKyriacou beside I get really hard time to get the OP question, every time he/she ask a new thing, you note that I makes many edits, and I agree there are better ways to solve this, I like to suggest a solution using Java 8 instead of `BufferedReader` this last is old now, NO?

Comment: I know, but Java 8 is not really good enough: what we need is a Java 10 Stream with its takeWhile and dropWhile methods.

Comment: Good one, I will try in my side to create a good one, you can also create your own @KlitosKyriacou

Comment: See my answer .

Answer (score 2):

YCF_L's answer gives the correct result, but if you have a very large file it will read the whole content into memory even if you only use a small part of it. To avoid this, and to process one line at a time, if you had Java 10 you could do it like this:

```
    try (Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(Paths.get("out/production/scratch/file.txt"))) {
        lines
                .dropWhile(line -> !line.equals("#22"))
                .skip(1)
                .takeWhile(line -> !line.equals("END"))
                .forEachOrdered(System.out::println);
    }
```

But you state that you only have Java 8, which lacks the `dropWhile` and `takeWhile` methods. Instead, you can use existing Java 7 methods:

```
    try (BufferedReader br = Files.newBufferedReader(Paths.get("out/production/scratch/file.txt"))) {
        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null && !line.equals("#22"))
            ;  // skip lines
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null && !line.equals("END"))
            System.out.println(line);
    }
```

Note that in both examples, the try-with-resources statement is used so that the file is automatically closed as soon as you encounter the first "END" line after "#22".

Comment: Nice answer I have a doubt that the user want to get all between #22 until the END after #33 but it's a nice answer uv from me

Comment: @YCF_L in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51723036/how-to-start-read-a-textfile-from-specific-line-using-java/51736464?noredirect=1#comment90407027_51723179) the OP said "I want text between #22 and END (_before_ #33)".

Comment: Hi @Klitos Kyriacou Yes the OP said after that [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51723036/how-to-start-read-a-textfile-from-specific-line-using-java/51736464?noredirect=1#comment90407964_51723179) what you get from this ;)